# How do I obtain an all caps month abbreviation with the R function `as.Date`

Tags: r

The `%b` code value in the `as.Date()` function yields a title case abbreviated month (eg Jan).

```
format(as.Date('2001-01-15'), format = '%b/%d/%Y')
#> [1] "Jan/15/2001"
```

The output I desire is an all Caps month abbreviation (eg JAN):

```
JAN/15/2001
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Can you try `toupper`?

Comment: Wrap it in a toupper()

Answer (score 0):

As r2evans and iod said, `toupper("Jan/15/2001")`

Or the stringr equivilant
`str_to_upper("Jan/15/2001")`